# custom date and time picker like in screenshot android

Tags: android, datetime

Is it possible to make a date and time picker like in screenshot having range of time intervals? 
[image: custom date and time picker]

Comment: I'm going to say: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Question closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that is is possible. They way I would go about approaching it is place a `scrollView` inside your activity with a`textView`and a `gridLayout` inside of that. Set the `numColumns=2`and then set `android:stretchMode=AUTO_FIT`. I would then place 7 `Custom Views` in there for the left column, and place 24 `Custom Views` into the right column. And then, of course add the `Button` at the bottom with its own styling.